# new Map() not supported on CouchDB? Looking for a good alternative

Tags: javascript, dictionary, view, mapreduce, couchdb

I'm trying to build a Map-reduce View with Futon on CouchDB. The map-part code is the following:

```js
function(doc) {
var m = new Map(); // dictionary
  m.set('molto', 'R');
  m.set('davvero', 'R');
  m.set('veramente', 'R');
  m.set('troppo', 'R');
  m.set('bel', 'R');
  m.set('bello', 'R');
  m.set('ben', 'R');
  m.set('molti', 'R');
  m.set('sicuramente', 'R');
  m.set('tante', 'R');
  m.set('incredibile', 'R');
  m.set('tanta', 'R');
  m.set('top', 'R');
  m.set('troppi', 'R');
  m.set('urla', 'R');
  m.set('assolutamente', 'R');
  m.set('boom', 'R');
  m.set('esattamente', 'R');
  m.set('grave', 'R');
  m.set('perfetto', 'R');
  m.set('riconferma', 'R');
  m.set('accusa', 'R');
  m.set('deciso', 'R');
  m.set('grande', 'P');
  m.set('#superstar', 'P');
  m.set('#napolivale', 'P');
  m.set('#brambillasindaco', 'P');
  m.set('bene', 'P');
  m.set('forza', 'P');
  m.set('VERO', 'P');
  m.set('sostegno', 'P');
  m.set('merita', 'P');
  m.set('lavoro', 'P');
  m.set('bravo', 'P');
  m.set('cuore', 'P');
  m.set('dema', 'P');
  m.set('tanti', 'P');
  m.set('vincere', 'P');
  m.set('buon', 'P');
  m.set('caro', 'P');
  m.set('masaniello', 'P');
  m.set('complimenti', 'P');
  m.set('futuro', 'P');
  m.set('buona', 'P');
  m.set('#stavotalettieri', 'P');
  m.set('coraggio', 'P');
  m.set('#sindaco', 'P');
  m.set('cara', 'P');
  m.set('cambiamento', 'P');
  m.set('#napolicapitale', 'P');
  m.set('leader', 'P');
  m.set('piace', 'P');
  m.set('proposte', 'P');
  m.set('risultati', 'P');
  m.set('#decidelacittÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('#napoliÃ©5stelle', 'P');
  m.set('dignitÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('finalmente', 'P');
  m.set('impegno', 'P');
  m.set('speciale', 'P');
  m.set('onestÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('passione', 'P');
  m.set('possibile', 'P');
  m.set('speranza', 'P');
  m.set('stile', 'P');
  m.set('successo', 'P');
  m.set('#sindacoxnapoli', 'P');
  m.set('fiducia', 'P');
  m.set('grandi', 'P');
  m.set('legalitÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('rivoluzione', 'P');
  m.set('voterei', 'P');
  m.set('#napolibenecomune', 'P');
  m.set('bellissima', 'P');
  m.set('idee', 'P');
  m.set('merito', 'P');
  m.set('pulita', 'P');
  m.set('sociale', 'P');
  m.set('uniti', 'P');
  m.set('valori', 'P');
  m.set('#iovotodemagistris', 'P');
  m.set('#iovotono', 'P');
  m.set('#lettierisindaco', 'P');
  m.set('#liberiamonapoli', 'P');
  m.set('#marapernapoli', 'P');
  m.set('libertÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('popolari', 'P');
  m.set('tifo', 'P');
  m.set('vinciamo', 'P');
  m.set('#corruzione', 'P');
  m.set('#lavoro', 'P');
  m.set('#pensioni', 'P');
  m.set('amore', 'P');
  m.set('belle', 'P');
  m.set('grandissimo', 'P');
  m.set('onesto', 'P');
  m.set('riuscito', 'p');
  m.set('sostiene', 'P');
  m.set('vincente', 'P');
  m.set('abbraccio', 'P');
  m.set('adoro', 'P');
  m.set('bellissimo', 'P');
  m.set('big', 'P');
  m.set('bravissimo', 'P');
  m.set('classe', 'P');
  m.set('compagno', 'P');
  m.set('convinto', 'P');
  m.set('luce', 'P');
  m.set('pizza', 'P');
  m.set('rielezione', 'P');
  m.set('riparte', 'P');
  m.set('#napoliautonoma', 'P');
  m.set('#ricominciodalleperiferie', 'P');
  m.set('libera', 'P');
  m.set('migliore', 'P');
  m.set('onesti', 'P');
  m.set('palle', 'P');
  m.set('popolare', 'P');
  m.set('ribelle', 'P');
  m.set('sicura', 'P');
  m.set('simpatico', 'P');
  m.set('stavolta', 'P');
  m.set('trasparenza', 'P');
  m.set('vamos', 'P');
  m.set('votiamo', 'P');
  m.set('#coraggio', 'P');
  m.set('#decidelacitta', 'P');
  m.set('#dema', 'P');
  m.set('#esserenapoletanovuoldire', 'P');
  m.set('#iovotoonesto', 'P');
  m.set('#stalotalettieri', 'P');
  m.set('brava', 'P');
  m.set('buone', 'P');
  m.set('piaciuto', 'P');
  m.set('rappresenta', 'P');
  m.set('splendido', 'P');
  m.set('stavota', 'P');
  m.set('#demagistrissindaco', 'P');
  m.set('#lungomareliberato', 'P');
  m.set('#savebikesharingnapoli', 'P');
  m.set('amo', 'P');
  m.set('applausi', 'P');
  m.set('buono', 'P');
  m.set('fortuna', 'P');
  m.set('funziona', 'P');
  m.set('gioia', 'P');
  m.set('libero', 'P');
  m.set('mafie', 'P');
  m.set('meriti', 'P');
  m.set('migliori', 'P');
  m.set('miracolo', 'P');
  m.set('opportunitÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('positivo', 'P');
  m.set('qualitÃ ', 'P');
  m.set('riscatto', 'P');
  m.set('sogno', 'P');
  m.set('soluzione', 'P');
  m.set('trasparenti', 'P');
  m.set('#iopartecipo', 'P');
  m.set('#iostocondemagistris', 'P');
  m.set('#masaniello', 'P');
  m.set('#napolipride', 'P');
  m.set('#resistenza', 'P');
  m.set('#riscetamento', 'P');
  m.set('#votafi', 'P');
  m.set('bravi', 'P');
  m.set('capace', 'P');
  m.set('coerenza', 'P');
  m.set('combatte', 'P');
  m.set('conoscere', 'P');
  m.set('consigli', 'P');
  m.set('credibile', 'P');
  m.set('cultura', 'P');
  m.set('docet', 'P');
  m.set('faremo', 'P');
  m.set('festa', 'P');
  m.set('no', 'N');
  m.set('cacare', 'N');
  m.set('male', 'N');
  m.set('vergogna', 'N');
  m.set('fine', 'N');
  m.set('problema', 'N');
  m.set('#lariachetira', 'N');
  m.set('cagare', 'N');
  m.set('peggio', 'N');
  m.set('perdere', 'N');
  m.set('volgaritÃ ', 'N');
  m.set('peccato', 'N');
  m.set('schifo', 'N');
  m.set('abusivi', 'N');
  m.set('degrado', 'N');
  m.set('attacca', 'N');
  m.set('peggiore', 'N');
  m.set('populismo', 'N');
  m.set('chiacchiere', 'N');
  m.set('palazzo', 'N');
  m.set('purtroppo', 'N');
  m.set('spese', 'N');
  m.set('vattene', 'N');
  m.set('indegne', 'N');
  m.set('merda', 'N');
  m.set('minacce', 'N');
  m.set('monnezza', 'N');
  m.set('morte', 'N');
  m.set('corrotti', 'N');
  m.set('povera', 'N');
  m.set('volgare', 'N');
  m.set('cazzo', 'N');
  m.set('fallimento', 'N');
  m.set('flop', 'N');
  m.set('minaccia', 'N');
  m.set('bugie', 'N');
  m.set('cacati', 'N');
  m.set('colpa', 'N');
  m.set('condannato', 'N');
  m.set('dispiace', 'N');
  m.set('distrutto', 'N');
  m.set('dubbio', 'N');
  m.set('errore', 'N');
  m.set('#caffÃ¨scorretto', 'N');
  m.set('#vergogna', 'N');
  m.set('becero', 'N');
  m.set('brutta', 'N');
  m.set('bruttezza', 'N');
  m.set('brutto', 'N');
  m.set('fallito', 'N');
  m.set('incapace', 'N');
  m.set('inutili', 'N');
  m.set('pessimo', 'N');
  m.set('roba', 'N');
  m.set('spieghi', 'N');
  m.set('tristezza', 'N');
  m.set('attacchini', 'N');
  m.set('bocciato', 'N');
  m.set('buffone', 'N');
  m.set('crisi', 'N');
  m.set('delirio', 'N');
  m.set('disastro', 'N');
  m.set('interista', 'N');
  m.set('ridicolo', 'N');
  m.set('rischio', 'N');
  m.set('sangue', 'N');
  m.set('solito', 'N');
  m.set('vergognati', 'N');
  m.set('violento', 'N');
  m.set('#gomorralaserie', 'N');
  m.set('culo', 'N');
  m.set('esodato', 'N');
  m.set('fallita', 'N');
  m.set('falsitÃ ', 'N');
  m.set('fastidio', 'N');
  m.set('non', 'I');
  m.set('mai', 'I');
  m.set('invece', 'I');
  m.set('meno', 'I');
  m.set('sbagliato', 'I');
  m.set('nessuna', 'I');
  m.set('not', 'I');
  m.set('contrario', 'I');
  m.set('diversa', 'I');
  m.set('#jungels', 'A');
  m.set('#moser', 'A');
  m.set('@giroditalia', 'A');
  m.set('#dumoulin', 'A');
  m.set('#nibali', 'A');
  m.set('#trentin', 'A');
  m.set('#roglic', 'A');
  m.set('#veloextra', 'A');
  m.set('crono', 'A');
  m.set('#gomorra2', 'A');
  m.set('maillot', 'A');
  m.set('#ciclismo', 'A');
  m.set('http//cyclismactunet', 'A');
  m.set('#girorai2016', 'A');
  m.set('#saichivoti', 'A');
  m.set('#eurosportciclismo', 'A');
  m.set('dumoulin', 'A');
  m.set('#fightforpink', 'A');
  m.set('#giroditalia2016', 'A');
  m.set('ciclabile', 'A');
  m.set('ciclismo', 'A');
  m.set('gregario', 'A');

 var sentiment = 0; 
  var words = doc.text.split(' '); 
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); // trim
    word = word.replace(/[?!.:,;-]/g,"");         // strip punctuation
    word = word.replace(/\"/g,"");                // strip escaped quotes
 word = word.toLowerCase();
    if( word.length > 0 ) {
  var prova = 0;

  if( m.has(word) ){
    var sentChar = m.get(word);
    switch (sentChar){
     case 'P':     
      sentiment = sentiment+1;
      break;
     case 'N':     
      sentiment = sentiment-1;
      break;
     case 'I':     
      prova = 0;
      break;
     case 'R':     
      prova = 0;
      break;
     case 'A':     
      prova=0;
      break; 
    }
  }
    


  
 }  
  }
  emit(doc.Candidato,sentiment);
}
```

I tried to run part of this code out of CouchDB passing an artificial phrase, and everything works. But it seems that CouchDB doesn't like new Map() or m.set();

This code should take a tweet and make a sentiment analysis on it based on this short dictionary ( Italian ), for example adding +1 or subtracting -1 to the sentiment variable of each word if it's in the dictionary and it's marked with P(Positive) or P(Negative). I have other cases too, with 'R' or 'A' in which i have to do different things.

The question is: why do Map() seems not working on CouchDB? what should i use to avoid a sequential search on an array? ( i have something like 20k tweets in my db )

Answer (score 0):

Map is an ES6 feature that is not supported in the version of Spidermonkey that CouchDB has included.

One option is to just use a plain object, the caveats/gotchas shouldn't apply in this case, since italian doesn't have the word `__proto__` in it's lexicon.

Another option is to switch to using newer versions (v4+) of Node.js as your query server. You can find instructions for that [in the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/experimental.html#nodejs-query-server). (it is labelled "experimental", so your mileage may vary)

If neither of those options is acceptable, you could also find a Map polyfill library and include it as a [CommonJS Module](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs-modules).

Personally, I find the plain object the most appealing, as it has the fewest downsides and the least amount of overhead given what I understand of the situation.